# Getting Invalid argument as a failure reason while enabling TCP keep alive option?

Tags: linux, tcp, tcp-keepalive

I have tried to implement TCP client to send TCP keep alive request but all the option were failed with **invalid argument**. My code looks like as below:

```
    #define SERVER_ADDRESS "94.23.3.169" /* Server address */
    #define PORT 1010/* the port client will be connecting to */
    
    
    static int16_t i16Sockfd;
    
    void vEnablekeepalive(int16_t i16Sockfd;)
    {
        int16_t i16Enable;
        socklen_t optlen = sizeof(i16Enable);
    
        /* Check the status for the keepalive option */
        if(getsockopt(i16Sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, &i16Enable, &optlen) < 0) {
            perror("getsockopt");
        }
        MSG("Before KEEP_ALIVE OPTION:%d\n",i16Enable);
    
        i16Enable = 1;
        if(setsockopt(i16Sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, &i16Enable, sizeof(i16Enable)) == -1){
            perror("setsockopt");
        }
    
        /* Check the status for the keepalive option */
        if(getsockopt(i16Sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, &i16Enable, &optlen) < 0) {
            perror("getsockopt);
        }
        MSG("After KEEP_ALIVE OPTION:%d\n",i16Enable);
    
        int16_t i16Idle = 600;
        if(setsockopt(i16Sockfd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_KEEPIDLE, &i16Idle, sizeof(i16Idle)) == -1){
            perror("Idle");
        }
    
        int16_t i16Interval = 60;
        if(setsockopt(i16Sockfd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_KEEPINTVL, &i16Interval, sizeof(i16Interval)) == -1){
            perror("Interval");
        }
    
        int16_t i16Maxcount = 5;
        if(setsockopt(i16Sockfd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_KEEPCNT, &i16Maxcount, sizeof(i16Maxcount)) == -1){
            perror("Maxcount");
        }
    }
    
    int main()
    {
        struct sockaddr_in their_addr;
        
        if ((i16Sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) == -1) {
            perror("socket");
        }
              
        Enablekeepalive(i16Sockfd);
    
        their_addr.sin_family = AF_INET; /* host byte order */
        their_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT); /* short, network byte order */
        their_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(SERVER_ADDRESS);
        zero(&(their_addr.sin_zero), 8); /* zero the rest of the struct */
        if (connect(i16Sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &their_addr,sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1) {
            perror("connect");
            close(i16Sockfd);
        }
              
    }
```

I can't get why it is giving invalid argument for all **setsockopt** API. Is there anything wrong to set keep alive option using setsockopt?

Comment: Why are you using `int16_t` for all the places that require an `int`? They are likely not the same size on your system.

Answer (score 1):

From the [`socket(7)` documentation](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html), which covers `SO_XXX` socket options:

> The socket options listed below can be set by using `setsockopt(2)` and read with `getsockopt(2)` with the socket level set to `SOL_SOCKET` for all sockets.  **Unless otherwise noted, `optval` is a pointer to an int.**

and

> `SO_KEEPALIVE`
> Enable sending of keep-alive messages on connection-oriented sockets. **Expects an integer boolean flag.**

The Linux-specific `TCP_KEEPIDLE` etc. options also expect an `int` argument.

An `int16_t` like you're using as the option type is unlikely to be the same size as an `int` on typical systems these days, hence the errors. Use `int` instead.

Answer (score 0):

SO_KEEPALIVE is for a connection oriented socket. So please connect your socket first and set SO_KEEPALIVE after that.

Comment: I have one more query:
If i have enable keep alive and set all option for keep alive using above code then do i need to change below setting?
**# echo 600 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_time
# echo 60 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_intvl
# echo 20 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_probes**

Comment: @AbhishekLakhara: You don't need to change the settings if you can live with the current settings. Note that you can also apply socket specific settings for the keep alive timings - see https://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/#setsockopt